# Reset countdown timer when button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button where when pressed the timer starts counting down. I am having a hard time figuring out how to reset the countdown timer once that same button is pressed.

I am also wondering why my time is stopping at 0:1??

```js
let startingCount = 5
let time = startingCount * 60
let spaceForTime = document.getElementById('countdown')


let myTimer = null

function timer() {

  if (myTimer !== null) {
    clearInterval(myTimer)
  }

  myTimer = setInterval(function timer() {
    let seconds = time % 60
    let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60)
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds
    time--;
    if (time >= 0) {
      spaceForTime.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`

    } else if (time === 0) {
      spaceForTime.innerText = "Move onto the next question!"
      clearInterval(time)
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="button">
  <button onclick="timer()" id="letsChat">Let's Chat!</button>
</div>
<span id="countdown"></span>
```

Comment: You need a global flag, something like `running`.  You can toggle it when the button is pressed, and have the timer stop itself when the value goes false.  Note that you will never take the `(time === 0)` path.  If time is 0, you'll take the `time >= 0` path instead.

Comment: pro-tip:  For your example, use a timeout that busy answerers will tolerate, like 5 seconds, not 5 minutes.

Comment: `time` variable has to be reset to start value. Set it to 300 again in your outter timer function.

Comment: thank you @Wyck I will keep in mind for next time!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to redeclare the `startingCount` and `time` variables ater you clear the previous interval inside `timer()`.

```js
let startingCount = 5
let time = 0 // set this inside timer()
let spaceForTime = document.getElementById('countdown')

let myTimer = null

function timer() {

  if (myTimer !== null) {
    clearInterval(myTimer)
  }
  
  time = startingCount * 60 // initialize the time here

  myTimer = setInterval(function timer() {
    let seconds = time % 60
    let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60)
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds
    time--;
    if (time >= 0) {
      spaceForTime.innerText = `${minutes}:${seconds}`
    } else {
      spaceForTime.innerText = "Move onto the next question!"
      clearInterval(time)
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="button">
  <button onclick="timer()" id="letsChat">Let's Chat!</button>
</div>
<span id="countdown"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I tried this and it works!! :) I appreciate it <3 Also do you happen to know why the timer stops at 0:1?

Comment: @studioair change your `else if` to `time < 0`, since `=== 0` will be captured in the initial `if` conition i.e. `>= 0`. You can actually just change the `else if` to just `else`.

Answer (score 0):

add a check in your timer function to see if the timer is already running. If it is, clear the interval and reset the time to its starting value before starting the timer again

```
let startingCount = 5
let time = startingCount * 60
let spaceForTime = document.getElementById('countdown')
let myTimer = null

function timer() {
  if (myTimer !== null) {
    clearInterval(myTimer)
    time = startingCount * 60
  }

  myTimer = setInterval(function() {
    let seconds = time % 60
    let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60)
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds

    if (time >= 0) {
      spaceForTime.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`
      time--;

    } else {
      spaceForTime.innerText = "Move onto the next question!"
      clearInterval(myTimer)
    }
  }, 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change that in your code:

```
let startingCount = 5
let time = startingCount * 60
let spaceForTime = document.getElementById('countdown')


let myTimer = null

function timer() {
 startingCount = 5;<---------
 if (myTimer !== null) {
   clearInterval(myTimer)
 }

myTimer = setInterval(function timer() {
let seconds = time % 60
let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60)
seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds
time--;
if (time >= 0) {
  spaceForTime.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`

} else{ <---------
  spaceForTime.innerText = "Move onto the next question!"
  clearInterval(time)
}
}, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the timer stops at 0:01 is because first, you set the `minutes` and `seconds` variables, then you decrease `time`. You need to decrease time before setting the `minutes` and `seconds` variables.

Answer (score 0):

A few points to consider:

First, the timer isn't resetting because you are not resetting the value of `time` (as others have mentioned).

Second, The reason it stops at 0:01 is because your `time--` comes before your if conditions, so the condition is evaluating `time == -1` on the iteration where it should show 0 second. The execution being:

```
--> currently showing 0:01.
--> new seconds calculated to be 00
--> time-- results in time = -1
--> condition fails since time < 0
--> does not show updated seconds
```

To resolve that, move the `time--` to the end of the interval function (aka after the if conditions).

Third, your `else if` condition is never accessed since you put `>=` in your if condition. It should be changed to strictly larger `>`.

Code with the above changes:

```js
let startingCount = .1;
let time = startingCount * 60;
let spaceForTime = document.getElementById('countdown');

let myTimer = null;

function timer() {

  if (myTimer !== null) {
    clearInterval(myTimer);
    time = startingCount * 60;
  }


  myTimer = setInterval(function timer() {
    let seconds = time % 60;
    let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
    if (time > 0) {
      spaceForTime.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;

    } else if (time === 0) {
      spaceForTime.innerText = "Move onto the next question!";
      clearInterval(time);
    }
    time--;
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="button">
  <button onclick="timer()" id="letsChat">Let's Chat!</button>
</div>
<span id="countdown"></span>
```

Note: shortened time to 6 seconds for faster demonstration